# How to trim a string after a specific character in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a string like "image.jpg". I want to save the image with its name, so i need to trim the image extension. Any methods in javascript to achieve that.

Comment: [`str.split(".")[0]`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) Check the split function. Or else you can also look at regular expressions.

Comment: `"some.image.jpg".replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to take `.` in the base name into account. This remove the last `.ext` value

```js
var fileName = "some.image.jpg";
var baseName = fileName.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');

$('div').text(baseName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what i need. Just to remove the image extension from the image name. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

```
str = 'image.test.jpg'

str.slice(0,str.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

This accounts for having `.` within the name of the image

Answer (score 1):

There is a [split function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) offered by javascript. Essentially what you are trying to do is split the string into array of strings based on the character you need.

```
var str = "image.jpg";
var array = str.split(".");
array.pop();
var imageName = array.join("");
```

PS: This is pure javascript so you don't really need any other library.

Comment: what if i have an image name something like 'image.image.jpg'. Then i would be left only with 'image' rather than 'image.image'.

Comment: updated the code to include popping the last element of array and then join it. It's simple string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript:

```
yourString = "image.jpg";    
yourString=yourString.replace('.jpg','');
```

Comment: good, but will need altering if the images is for example a .png, best to use split('.')

Comment: I agree, but what if the name contains a "."? He can also add multipule lines of yourString.replace with the other types of images.

Comment: as per above something like str.slice(0,str.lastIndexOf('.')) make more sense. having multiple replace lines would bloat your code where as using split/spice keeps it DRY